# How to import .ppk file in WinSCP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, winscp

How to import .ppk file into WinSCP?
While I am try to connect **WinSCP** to the cloud server it's showing **Authentication failed** error.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open **Winscp**
2. Go to **Session** window, fill the details with **Host name** **Username** and **password**
3. Click on **Edit** button, then it will highlight the **Advanced** button.
4. Click on that,
5. select **SSH** → **Authentication** on the left side,
6. select the path of **Private key file**.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the SSH tab in my settings, I forgot to set protocol to SFTP in my case: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication

Comment: Any idea what's the earliest version of WinSCP that supports this?
Furthermore, doesn't using a PPK file mean there's no password?